# No inv messages from inbound nodes

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, protocol, raw-transaction, peers, inventory

I'm writing a tx relay-only node that can accept inbound connections and make outbound ones. Just for research.

What I'm seeing that on inbound nodes the initial handshake completes and the connection just hangs, I should receive invs shouldn't I?

For outbound it works great, I receive invs and redistribute to others.

Tx relay flag is set in version msg for both direction. Services field is 0. What else do I need?

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't being disconnected? If you don't have any service bits set, nodes will probably end up disconnecting from you since they are expecting their outbounds to have at least the service bits NODE_NETWORK and NODE_WITNESS.

Comment: Turns out there are a lot of scanner nodes just connected to me and asked version then just sit silently, I have set up a full node that only connected to me and to another node and I was seeing incoming invs. Thanks though!